# Moscow lay as a crossing of three roads

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

What is the grammatical role of the "lay" in the following sentence? It seems like a verb. But why it is not used like a third person form (lays) or "lay" is the past form of it?

> First, attention may be given to the doctrine of geographic causation.
>   It stresses the decisive importance of the location on Moscow for the
>   later expansion of the Muscovite state (the medieval state centered in
>   Moscow) and includes several lines of argument. **Moscow lay as a
>   crossing of three roads**. The most important was the way from the
>   historically crucial city of Kiev and the declining south to the
>   growing northeast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Lay*** is also used as [the simple past tense of *lie*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lay), particularly when it is used to refer to or denote position.

Comment: By the way, do you think that the form in the question "Moscow lay as a crossing..." is valid, or should it be "Moscow lay at a crossing" or "Moscow lay on a crossing" ? see my answer and the comments on it.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: It's valid, just unusual. You've seen already that *lay as X* is valid, even if you don't get many results for *lay as a crossing*; there's nothing special about what words can be there. It was sitting in a position, and acted as a crossroads.

Answer (score 3):

It is a verb. It is the past tense of "lie".

This is confusing, as there is another verb with the present tense "lay". The difference is that "lie" is not used with an object

> Lie on the floor.
>   Moscow lay at the crossing of three roads.
>   I have lain here for three hours.

But "lay" is used with an object.

> Lay the book on the floor.
>   She laid the book on the table.
>   The chicken has laid an egg.

However, although this is the "rule", it is frequently broken. You will hear native speakers saying "Lay on the floor".

Comment: Historically, _to lay_ was a causative formed from _to lie_, just as _to raise_ was a causitive of _to rise_, and _to set_ was a causitive of _to sit_. This formation is no longer productive in English. As you say, _lay_ is also the past of _lie_, hence the confusion you mention at the end. In many people's speech _to lie_ has been entirely replaced by _to lay_ (in this sense. It still remains in the sense "to tell a falsehood", of course.)

Comment: By the way, do you think that the form in the question "Moscow lay as a crossing..." is valid, or should it be "Moscow lay at a crossing" or "Moscow lay on a crossing" ? see my answer and the comments on it.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this is an editing error for:

> Moscow lay at a crossing of three roads

In such a construction, "lay" or "lay on" or "lay at" means "was located", and is a past tense of "to lie".

The [merriam-webster definition of "lie"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lie) (sense 1, meaning 5a) is:

> to occupy a certain relative place or position

One could also write:

> New York City lies on an excellent natural harbor.

or

> Philadelphia lies southeast of New York.

Comment: Not an error. It's the actual form of the actual verb to use.

Comment: @Robusto  "Lay **as**? Do you have a source for that form? "Lay" is surely correct. I have seen "lay on" and "lay at" (and "lie/lies on/at depending on tense) with this meaning, but never "lay as".

Comment: Yes. You should look up *as* in a dictionary, where you'll see it's a synonym for *like*. Do you seriously mean to suggest *verb + like* is wrong or even a little bit strange?

Comment: @Robusto A dictionary will show many meanings for a basic word such as "as" not all of which apply in all cases. "Like" and "as" are certainly not interchangeable. and *verb* +  like is highly unusual, and probably wrong when the verb is "to lie" in the sense of position. "He lay like a dead man"  is valid. "The city lay like a road": is nonsense. "The city lay on a road" is normal.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I think *Moscow lay as a crossing* can reasonably be interpreted as saying, in effect, that it *was* a crossing. A more literary rendition might read *Moscow lay a crossing*. (I'm not a native speaker of English, though, so *cum grano salis*.)

Comment: @userr2684291  I do not think that either "*Moscow lay as a crossing*" or "*Moscow lay a crossing*" is grammatically correct English, particularly not the second of those.  Can you point to a source that has used "lay as" or "lie as" to mean "was/is positioned at"? I may be mistaken, but I don't think so.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Searching the *Corpus of Historical American English*, I find: *The mountains ceased to glow as the clouds above them grew dull, and from softest blue vanished into darkest purple; banks of misty clouds settled into the valleys about their summits; the light wind died away; **the river lay a silent roadway**; the vast forests took on a denser shade, and the whole world of nature slept as the mother watched.* from *Le Coureur Des Bois* by Annie T. Howells, published in 1878.

Comment: From [The English Constitution (1894)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:The_English_Constitution_(1894).djvu/117): *He had not to deal with a community in which primitive barbarism **lay as** a recognised basis to acquired civilisation.*

Comment: @userr2684291  in your first case, the river is being compared to a roadway (an implied simile) it is not positioned along a roadway or at a roadway. This is also not exactly current usage. In the second case, it seems be comparing barbarism to civilization, and is not a specification of position.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Oh, yeah, I never said *X lay as a Y* means "X was positioned at a Y"; I said it means "X ~was (could be compared to) a Y", and that's what the citations are supposed to show. Sorry, I didn't read your request fully, but I did read the part where you claim that such constructions are ungrammatical. And sure, it's not exactly current, but that's why I described the first one as literary, while the second one I found was conveniently sitting there, so I just plucked it.

Comment: @userr2684291 What I said, or meant to say was that neither "X lay as Y" nor "X lay as a Y" is valid **when the intended meaning is to indicate a position of X**, which seems to me to be the intent in the question. Others seem to be asserting the contrary.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Who knows what the intent was; we only know what's written, and given the context (which doesn't seem to favor any particular interpretation) I'm of the opinion that *Moscow lay as a crossing of three roads* can be reasonably interpreted as saying "Moscow was or played the role of a crossing of three roads", and I've shown you quotations where *lie as* is used in that exact way. You haven't shown why the *as* at issue should be considered a typo for *at*.